# How to POST a derived entity to a base entity set

Tags: odata

Suppose I have a base entity type named Employee and a derived entity type named Manager. And the set of all Employees is accessible at the `/Employees` URL. What is the correct way to POST an instance of Manager to the Employees entity set?

The [OData v4 protocol spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398326) says "To create an entity in a collection, the client sends a POST request to that collection's URL." But the spec does not say anything about specifying the type of the POSTed entity in a scenario where derived types exist.

The [URI spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398088) says derived types should be addressed using a cast segment on the target URL. For example,

```
POST /Employees/NS.Manager
{ "Name": "Bill Lumbergh" ... }
```

Meanwhile, the [JSON Format spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940617) suggests using the `odata.type` annotation as follows:

```
POST /Employees
{ "@odata.type": "#NS.Manager", "Name": "Bill Lumbergh" ... }
```

So which is correct? Or are both?

Please keep in mind that I am asking with respect to the OData specifications, not a specific OData library/framework (e.g. ASP.NET).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an OData Protocol perspective, if you are specifying an instance in a JSON request that is derived from the target type you should include the @odata.type annotation. You do not need to specify the cast segment on the POST (though some implementations may support that, some may not).

So I would expect your second example to be the most interoperable.

Mike Pizzo
Co-Editor, OASIS OData Specifications

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was expecting the POST-with-cast approach to be preferred, but upon reflection I guess it makes more sense for the JSON payload to be self-describing. However, the value of the `@odata.type` property (a URI pointing to a metadata document) is not as perspicuous as the value of a cast segment (a namespace-qualified type name).

Answer (score 2):

## In my option, both are correct, however there's a little bit difference.

For #1,

```
POST /Employees/NS.Manager
{ "Name": "Bill Lumbergh" ... }
```

you will get a `Manager` instance. So, you can directly access the property defined to `Manager`.

For #2,

```
POST /Employees
{ "@odata.type": "#NS.Manager", "Name": "Bill Lumbergh" ... }
```

you will get a `Employee` instance. So, you should cast the instance to `Manager` then to access the `Manager` property.

## From the Web API OData implementation aspect:

For #1,  it will invoke the following method in `EmployeesController`

```
public IHttpActionResult PostFromManager(Manager manager)
{ ... }
```

While, for #2, it will invoke the following method in `EmployeesController`

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee employee)
 { ... }
```

Comment: I think you have your Web API methods reversed. The URI with the cast (`/Employees/NS.Manager`) will be routed to PostFromManager(), while the bare URI will be routed to Post().

Comment: Oops. Thanks your clarification. I updated my answer.